# About the meaning of identification space

Tags: general-topology, equivalence-relations, quotient-spaces

when I am learning topology, specifically identification space, I have a confusion about this question.

Consider the following Mobius strip: $M = [0,1]*[0,1]/(0,y)$ ~ $(1, 1 - y)$ and the closed unit circle $D = ${$(\rho, \theta)| \rho\leq1$}.

And then we have a map: $f(1, \theta) = (\theta/\pi, 1)$ if $0\leq\theta\leq\pi$ or $= (\theta/\pi -1, 0)$if $\pi\leq\theta\leq2\pi$ . I think such a map maps the boundary of the unit disc, a circle, to the boundary of the Mobius strip, right?

The question asks me to explain what is the following identification map:

$D \cup_fM$. I am not quite certain what does this question  mean, what does the identification space mean?

Comment: Yes, this maps the circle (boundary of the unit disc) to the boundary of the Möbius strip. The question asks you to describe the adjunction space $D\cup_fM$, this is quotient space obtained from the disjoint union $D\sqcup M$ by identifying an element $(1,\theta)\in D$ with $f(1,\theta)\in M$ respectively for all $\theta$. This space is homeomorphic to some other well-known space, which is probably what the question wants you to discover.

Comment: So do you know what is possibly be such well - known space...

Comment: Yes, but that is besides the point (and for you to think about yourself), Your question is about the meaning of an identification space. Is it clear to you now what the identification space in the question means (by definition) or does confusion remain?